# Angular2 test - not detecting changes

Tags: testing, jasmine, angular

I'm trying to check a dropdown is shown when a boolean is switched.
The boolean is an input on the component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dropdown',
    directives: [NgClass],
    template: `
        <div [ngClass]="{open: open}">
        </div>
    `,
})

export class DropdownComponent {
    @Input('open') open: boolean = false;
}
```

And the test

```
it('should open', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
    return tcb.createAsync(DropdownComponent)
    .then(fixture => {
        let el = fixture.nativeElement;
        let comp: DropdownComponent = fixture.componentInstance;

        expect(el.className).toEqual('');

        comp.open = true;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(el.className).toEqual('open')
    });
}));
```

I am guessing something different has to be done when the boolean is an @Input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting class `open` on  the `<div [ngClass]="{open: open}">` but checking on `DropdownComponent`. That's not the same.

Something like this should do what you want

```
var div = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('div');
expect(div.className).toEqual('open');
```

or

```
var div = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('div'));  
expect(div.className).toEqual('open');
```

See also [How do I trigger a ngModel model update in an Angular 2 unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143859/how-do-i-trigger-a-ngmodel-model-update-in-an-angular-2-unit-test) for an example.

Comment: I console.log'd the "el" and it was a div. So what is the nativeElement from start? Is it some container above the component?

Comment: It should be `dropdown`, the selector of your component. The child of the element should be `div`. Maybe the `TestComponentBuilder` doesn't create a proper tag for your component. Didn't investigate that closely.